# QBWebConnector for multi-tenant DB

Tags: quickbooks

I want to use the QBWebConnector for an app that has multi-tenant DB. It means I need to know the tenant when my app receives data from QBWebConnector to populate the DB correctly.

I am using a PHP kit from consolibytes.

What are my options here?

I see that the functions which are called for building and receiving XML request have params like $user and $extra.

The $user is the user which is used by QBWebConnector to authenticate with the SOAP server.

So should I create multiple QWC files for each tenant as a user and use that to identify the tenant?

And what is this $extra in the param? Should I use that? If then how?

I also see we have callback options and hooks when we create QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server. I am not sure the use of them but can they be used in any way?

Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

> So should I create multiple QWC files for each tenant as a user and use that to identify the tenant?

Each tenant in your application should have their own username, and thus their own `.QWC` file.

If your application has multiple users per tenant, you do *not* need a `.QWC` file per user. You need a `.QWC` file *per tenant*.

> And what is this $extra in the param? Should I use that?

The `$extra` param is for passing additional data to your callback functions. It has nothing to do with tenancy or authentication, so don't use it for that.

> I also see we have callback options and hooks when we create QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server. I am not sure the use of them but can they be used in any way?

They can be used, but not for tenancy or authentication.

Comment: So the Quickbooks_user table can hold more than one user...one per tenant which can be used for QBWebConnector authentication?

The enqueue () does not take any argument for storing the current user in the Quuckbooks_queue table. Do I need to change the code for that?

Comment: I saw that QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue accepts a user parameter, so i think it can be used.

Comment: The `->enqueue()` method _DOES_ have a `$user` parameter. See:
https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/QuickBooks/WebConnector/Queue.php#L208

Correct, the `quickbooks_user` table can hold more than one user - one user per tenant. 

No, you do not need to change any of the library code.